# Having a Dynamic "For" in SQL Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

Hope everyone's having a good day!

I adjusted the question a bit as now only 1 part remaining.

Mainly im struggling with the @ContractDates variable, so that it would be used for each row in the Pivot statement. It uses @ContractStart and @ContractEnd, which are set to specific Columns before, but i think when i do it in that way, it selects the last row.

Example of the current table:

```
Client Name   Client Details  Start Date  End Date  Contract Length  USD Amount   Monthly Rate

 CLient 1       Details 1     01-06-2017  30-09-2017        4             800          200
```

Desired Result:

```
Client Name   Client Details   Start Date  End Date  Contract Length  USD Amount  Jun'17   Jul'17   Aug'17   Sep'17

 Client 1       Details 1      01-06-2017  30-09-2017         4          800       200       200     200     200
```

---

```
DECLARE @PivotColumns NVARCHAR(MAX),   --<Already pulling all columns currently in a format of [MMM'YY,MMM'YY,...]
        @ContractDates NVARCHAR(MAX),--<Dynamic variable that takes @ContractStart and @ContractEnd and converts it to the same format as @PivotColumns
        @ContractStart Datetime,
        @ContractEnd Datetime,
        @SQLQuery   NVARCHAR(MAX);

----Assigning row dates to be used for @ContractDates
Select  @ContractStart = [Start Date],
        @ContractEnd = [End Date]
From [dbo].[D_InvoiceExport_TrendTest]

Set @SQLQuery = 
    N'SELECT *,' + @PivotColumns + '
    FROM [dbo].[D_InvoiceExport_TrendTest]
    PIVOT( sum([Monthly Rate])
FOR (' + @ContractDates + ') IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) as P'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Thanks jarlh, added SQL 2008

Comment: It's still really hard to understand what you want. Can you provide some examples of the source table, the desired resulting query (i.e. an example value of @SQLQuery) and the desired output table?

Comment: Hi Rory, added the current table and desired result